# SQL QUERY search only full words, not parts just of string

Tags: mysql, sql

The actual SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (title LIKE '%but%' OR description LIKE '%but%');
```

[The query matches the word '**but**' and also the word 'distri**but**ion'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhHCe.png)

What would query look like to search only for whole words, but not just any character sequences?

Comment: This has little to do with PHP, but rather an SQL query. Please, update your question title to clearly state question and remove anything not related to SQL query. Also, give textual examples to remove link to external screenshot.

Comment: upss sorry sir .... i updated this question . accept my apology english is not my native language sir  .I'm trying to learn how to use phpmyadmin sir